# Measure of a set of trajectories

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, ergodic-theory

In ergodic systems, the average over the whole space equals the average over the trajectories
starting from almost every point $x$.

This is often described saying: "the average over the space is equal to the average over almost every trajectory". Google says that "almost every trajectory" appears more than ten thousend times.

It could be just a shortcut, but, rigorously, we can say "almost every trajectory" if there is a measure of sets of trajectories. It would be a measure of sets of sets of $X$ (sic! I did not repeat "set" by mistake). Does this measure really exist? Can you give a literature reference?

I tried this, very trivial. Given a measure $\mu$ of a space $X$, $\mu : P(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ (where $P(X)$ is the power set of $X$), I can define $\mu' : P[P(X)] \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $\mu'(S)=\mu(T)$ where $T$ is the union of all the elements of $S$. I
do not know if it is possible to find a suitable $\sigma$-algebra such that this $\mu'$ is really
a measure. Actually, I am more interested in knowing whether a widely-known definition of such a measure exists, rather than in the details, e.g. a literature reference to some popular book on measure theory.

Comment: While this does not address the actual question (which is certainly interesting in and of itself), nonetheless in the context of such quotes discussing ergodic transformations, the intention is that the phrase "almost every trajectory" is an abbreviation of the phrase "the trajectory of almost every point".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want, because it's a little trivial. But here's *an* answer. I don't know if this is at all considered in the literature.

$\newcommand{\T}{\mathscr{T}}$Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu;\varphi)$ be a measure preserving dynamical system (ergodic too, if you wish). A trajectory (I know it as "orbit") is a set $T_x:=\{\varphi^n(x):n\in\Bbb N_0\}$ where $x\in X$ is distinguished. Maybe let's call the set of all trajectories $\T$.

There is a bijection $\T\cong X$ through $T_x\sim x$. You can make $\T$ a measure space via this identification: $U\subseteq\T$ is measurable iff. $U$'s identification in $X$ is measurable. Then $\mu$ extends naturally to a measure on $\T$. Under this measuring, indeed (when $\varphi$ is ergodic) the space-average is equal to the average of a typical trajectory, "typical" meaning for almost every trajectory.

This could be seen as a justification for the terminology 'almost every [trajectory]' you are finding on Google.

Comment: I think it is correct. It is also simple, but can we consider it as common knowledge? Do you think that the terminology "almost every trajectory" can be safely used in a paper? I mean, without discussing the definition of measure on the set of trajectories.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli I’m not a paper author, but I should think it’s ok to say that in the more informal areas of a paper. Maybe, in a technical proof, avoid this language and say the ‘trajectory of almost any point’.